# RQ Flask Heroku worker application context

Tags: python, flask, redis, sqlalchemy, worker

have app.py:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

with app.app_context():
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
    app.debug = True

    db.app = app
    db.init_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

and worker.py:

```
import os
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

and other file containing

```
q = Queue(connection=conn)
q.enqueue(process_data, data)
```

where process_data is a function using db (sqlalchemy)

How should I pass the app context to the worker? 
the error is:

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 153, in __init__:
self.app = app = db.get_app()
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no application bound to current context
```

Answer (score 0):

solved and works like a charm by moving the entire code related to app config from app.py in init.py (excepting app.run()) and in app.py import app

Comment: Can you post the example code? I'm running into the same issue.